# Make Ms Word file part of dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

We have a class library project that is using Gembox which we use to create pdf files. Part of the workflow is to read templates from .docx files. We would like to embed these word file in the dll file that is created by the build, at the moment they are placed next to the dll file in the bin-folder.

Any suggestions in how we can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them to your resources file:

[image]

Then you can access them like this:

```
byte[] fileData = ProjectsNamespace.Properties.Resources.file;
```